Who builds the p2 repository https://download.eclipse.org/staging/yyyy-mm/?
I'm organizing the release process for my own project and would like to refer to eclipse.
I found that a p2 repository like https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2024-12/ is used in epp.
I'd like to know who is building this staging repository, and preferably see how it's written in the pom.xml file. Thanks.

The Eclipse SimRel project builds the

https://download.eclipse.org/staging/... and
https://download.eclipse.org/releases/...

p2 repositories by aggregating the repositories that are specified in the .aggrcon files. SimRel does this by running Jenkins jobs (see Jenkinsfile) using this pom.xml file.
